# Can I set Subject (aka Prn) in AppEngineTokenSource?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to call the Admin sdk from google AppEngine using Go, I have already done the following:

- Added Admin SDK to my appengine project
- added the appengine-project-name@appspot.gserviceaccount.com to the service accounts for the project

Following the example here https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#example-AppEngineTokenSource

I'm getting: Error 403: Not Authorized to access this resource/api, forbidden

When I did this from the command line, I had to set the Subject account.  Is there a way to do this with AppEngineTokenService?

```
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &oauth2.Transport{
        Source: google.AppEngineTokenSource(ctx,
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"),
        Base: &urlfetch.Transport{
            Context: ctx,
        },
    },
}

svc, err := admin.New(client)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error getting svc\n")
    ctx.Errorf("error getting service %v", err)
}
usersvc := admin.NewUsersService(svc)

listcall := usersvc.List()
listcall.Domain("example.com")
users, err := listcall.Do()
```

Comment: You can grant the service account access to certain scopes in the Control Panel as explained in the Google Drive domain-wide documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account. Use Admin SDK scopes instead.

Comment: I did this for the offline service account.  I don't have a client_id for the appengine account, only an email address which that page will not accept.  Do you know how I can register the appengine service account?

Comment: Did you try this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating

Comment: That link looks to me like it explains setting up a project, which I already have done.  You can find the service account name on the appengine settings page as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/prediction_service_accounts   The problem I have is that I don't know the client_id for the service account, so I cannot figure out how to grant it API access.  The service account name is like project-name@appspot.gserviceaccount.com but it needs to be a domain, not an email address.

Comment: Turns out the appengine service account does have access to the admin api - it just doesn't have access to my Google Apps domain information.  I think the way to allow it access is to specify the Subject name, but I don't see how to do this.